# How to comprehend "std::future shared state"?

Tags: c++, c++11

As per the documentation(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/future/get/), which says that:
[emphasis mine]

> Once the **shared state** is ready, the function unblocks and returns (or
>   throws) releasing its shared state. This makes the future object no
>   longer valid: this member function shall be called once at most for
>   every **future shared state**.

As per the documentation(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/future/), which says that:
[emphasis mine]

> "Valid" futures are future objects associated to **a shared state**, and
>   are constructed by calling one of the following functions
>
> > async
> >
> > promise::get_future
> >
> > packaged_task::get_future

As per the documentation(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/future/get/), which says that:
[emphasis mine]

> std::future::get
>
> > generic template (1) T get(); reference
> >
> > specialization (2) R& future::get();  // when T is a reference
> >
> > type (R&) void specialization (3)    void future::get();   // when T is void
>
> Return:
>
> > value Generally (1), std::move(x), where x is the value stored in **the shared state**.
> >
> > For references (2), a reference to the value stored in **the shared state**.
> >
> > For void futures (3), nothing.

**My question is what is the "`std::future` shared state"? How can i comprehend  "std::future shared state"?**

I am a novice in C++.Though I thought and thought about it, but I still can't grasp the idea. I would be very grateful to have some help with this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) documentation on `std::future`:

> When the asynchronous operation is ready to send a result to the creator, it can do so by modifying shared state (e.g. std::promise::set_value) that is linked to the creator's std::future.

Shared state here refers to some mutable stuff readable/writeable by multiple threads. Consider the example straight from the docs:

```
std::promise<int> p;
std::future<int> f = p.get_future();
std::thread([&p]{ p.set_value_at_thread_exit(9); }).detach();
f.wait();
```

The main thread and the created thread share `p` (and since `p` is stateful, they share state!). Calling `std::promise::set_value_at_thread_exit` inside the body of the lambda effectively modifies shared state between these two threads. This is essentially all that is meant.

The `std::future` given by the promise is a representation of the "interesting" part of the shared state -- the value you care about.